# Does that post qualify as a low quality post?

Tags: support

My flagging has been refused for that [post](https://serverfault.com/questions/900997/mariadb-host-127-0-0-1-not-privileged). Does posting just your configuration, without anything explaining the setup, is considered so ? Or should it be flagged as **should be closed** instead ?

**should be closed...**
This question is completely unclear, incomplete, overly-broad, primarily opinion-based or is not about server, networking, or related infrastructure administration as described in the help center, and it is unlikely to be fixed via editing.

**very low quality**

This question has severe formatting or content problems. This question is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't process your flag. But as far as I can tell, based on my familiarity with the subject matter, everything necessary to answer the question is present. It might be *improved* by adding a more detailed description, and it might not. Or a person more well versed in MySQL than I am might want some additional information. I have to disagree that the post is "unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed."

Comment: Mhhh makes sense. Thanks for the clarification !

Comment: And...actually I'm pretty sure my own mediocre knowledge of MySQL was sufficient to answer it.

Comment: Also, is there a way to know for how long we've been banned ? Nothing seems to indicate that.